# Using dates in Amazon Lex Conditional branching

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lex

I'm creating a bot without any integration with my database, and I'm using only the user's input to determine the answer.

I want to ask the user for a date. Then, I want to calculate how many days has passed and depending on the days, give A or B answer.

Example:
Bot: How many days since you returned the package?
User: 2 days
*if < 8 days...*
Bot: You'll receive your refund 8 business after returning the package.

I've created a slot in which I ask the user how many has passed when this information is not provided. However, I has not figured out how to calculate the time difference between the user's answer and today. In the conditional branching, I miss some field that could represent the session date for example.

I'd like to avoid the use of lambda if possible as I do not have knowlodge about code.